# What is the proper way to use factory in controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to write emphasis code only once. How can I achieve that? On    submit, I want to perform to task

1. To save data in Database
2. Render the submitted data on UI

**Code**

```
    .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http, getDataService) {
        $scope.submit = function () {
            var Employee = { "empID": $scope.empId, "Name":   $scope.empName, "Gender": $scope.empGender }
            $http(
          {
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://localhost:58365/home/saveEmpData',
              data: { emp: Employee },
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON;  charset=UTF-8' }
          }).then(function (response) {
              $scope.data123 = response.data;
          });

            **getDataService.fetchuserDetails().then(function (response)
            { $scope.data1 = response.data; });**
        }

        **getDataService.fetchuserDetails().then(function (response)
        { $scope.data1 = response.data; });**  

         })
```

**Factory**

```
        .factory("getDataService", ['$http', function ($http) {
            var obj = {};
            obj.fetchuserDetails = function ()
            {
                return $http.get('http://localhost:58365/home/GetEmpData');
            }

            return obj;
        }])
```

Answer (score 0):

To Save data in database,

```
$scope.saveData = function (xyz) {
   getDataService.save(xyz, function () {

      // write action you want to perform after saving your data

   })
};
```

Call **saveData( )** method in HTML and pass the variable where you are getting data or the variable where you are going to store temporary data.

To render submitted data it's better to write another controller.
Then run **`.query()`** method or **`.get()`** and collect it in one `$scope` variable.

Comment: if i write a separate controller ther how i will call that controller on same time..

Comment: You have to show data on same page or on different page ?
if on different page :- then maintain seperate controllers &
if on same pge :- then use same controller with different scope variables